# Chef:Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[httpd]'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-recipe, bootstrapping

I am using chef to create a server in AWS Amazon Environment using knife ec2 plugin.

I have created the EC2 Server using the following command:

```
knife ec2 server create --image ami-7c807d14 --flavor t1.micro --region us-east-1 --security-group-ids sg-ID --ebs-size 10 --ebs-no-delete-on-term --tags Name=Test_Server --server-connect-attribute private_ip_address  --subnet subnet-ID --ssh-user ec2-user --identity-file ~/.ssh/key.pem --environment Testing --node-name Redhat-Server
```

When I ssh to the Chef Node and run the following command  `sudo chef-client` to install apache on the node, it gives me an error:

````
[2014-06-24T07:44:55+00:00] WARN:
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
attacks.

To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:

```
  # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
  ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

  # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
  verify_api_cert true
```

To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
`knife ssl check` command like so:

```
  knife ssl check -c /etc/chef/client.rb
```

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

Starting Chef Client, version 11.12.8
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["apache-tutorial-1"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - apache-tutorial-1
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 4 resources
Recipe: apache-tutorial-1::default
  * package[httpd] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[httpd]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides ----
STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-devel kernel-source installonlypkg(kernel) installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm)
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from amzn-main: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides ----
Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache-tutorial-1/recipes/default.rb

 11: package 'httpd' do
 12:   action :install
 13: end
 14:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/apache-tutorial-1/recipes/default.rb:11:in `from_file'

package("httpd") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "httpd"
  cookbook_name "apache-tutorial-1"
  recipe_name "default"
end




Running handlers:
[2014-06-24T07:45:04+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-06-24T07:45:04+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-06-24T07:45:04+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 9.101137934 seconds
[2014-06-24T07:45:04+00:00] ERROR: package[httpd] (apache-tutorial-1::default line 11) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides ----
STDOUT: [option installonlypkgs] kernel kernel-devel kernel-source installonlypkg(kernel) installonlypkg(kernel-module) installonlypkg(vm)
STDERR: yum-dump Repository Error: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from amzn-main: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
---- End output of /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides ----
Ran /usr/bin/python /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.8/lib/chef/provider/package/yum-dump.py --options --installed-provides returned 1
[2014-06-24T07:45:05+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
````

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: May be you should ask this question on ServerFault.

Comment: But i have seen Chef related questions on SO also !!!!

Comment: Then my mistake sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was some problem with yum on Linux AMI.

The same command I ran to create centos machine worked.